# Prove that EFZY is a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry, quadrilateral

The incircle of $\Delta ABC$ touches $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ at $D$, $E$, and $F$ respectively. $X$ is a point inside $\Delta ABC$ such that the incircle of $\Delta XBC$ touches $BC$ at $D$ also, and touches $CX$ and $XB$ at $Y$ and $Z$, respectively. Prove that $EFZY$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

In this question, I can follow up to the point $P$, $Z$, $Y$ are declared collinear.
But after that , how does $$PF\cdot PE=PZ\cdot PY$$ confirm that $EFZY$ is a cyclic quadrilateral?

[image]

Comment: The points $P,E,F$ are on a line, and the points $P,Z,Y$ are on a line. The relation $PE\cdot PF= PY\cdot PZ$ is a known relation when $EFZY$ is cyclic, the key-word is the power of a point w.r.t. a circle. Here we need the other direction. It is enough to reverse the proof for the power of a point w.r.t. a circle being constant. This is done in the answer below. Please consider accepting the answer, if it satisfies the needs, else please tell us what is not clear. (It is a good policy to accept answers, so that unanswered issues are not surviving without reason on the site.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the figure, $PE \cdot PF = PZ \cdot PY \implies \Delta PEY \sim \Delta PZF$

Hence $\angle PEY = \angle PZF $

and $EFZY$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: Thank you for the answer